# Post counter in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have finished building a directory website and I would like to put something in the footer that counts how many total listing are on the site.

For example: If 20 people make a listing on my site I would like the footer to say "Total listings: 20".

A site that has this would be Themeforest.net. At the bottom of the page they have "Total items (number)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check wp_count_post() function : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_count_posts

```
<?php $count_posts = wp_count_posts('the-post-type'); ?>
```